# Add border to table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a border to my table using jQuery if something is true but can't get it to work:

```
$(function(){
$('table.test').css({'border':'1px solid red'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8San/

Comment: Answer : http://jsfiddle.net/m8San/1/  JQuery library missing

Comment: Forgot to add jQuery ?

Comment: You didn't specify `jQuery` library in your fiddle.

Comment: Answer http://jsfiddle.net/m8San/4/

Comment: Its working. You need to include jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

table border is not a css property.it is attribute of table.so use this code

```
$('table.test').attr("border","1px");
```

See this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/m8San/12/